# Trouble Returning The Count of Days Past Due

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, plpgsql

I am trying to build a function to return the count of days past due where the customer was less than 3 days late. Using the dvdrental database provided by PostgreSQL. It seems as though it's returning 6 for every row, likely the count of the first customer it comes across, or at least that's my guess.

Here's what I'm trying and what I need help on:

Example data:

| Customer_ID | days_past_due |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |

Expected result (count of days past due less than 3 found in file returned on each row of that customer_id):

| Customer_ID | days_past_due |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 |

```
create or replace function pd_lt3(customer_id varchar(45),days_past_due smallint)
returns smallint
language plpgsql
as $$
declare pd_lt3 smallint;
begin
    
    select total from(
    select customer_id,count(*) as total from past_due_detail where days_past_due < 3 group by customer_id
        )
    into pd_lt3;
    return pd_lt3;
end;
$$;
```

## *More Background (all of the below seems to work as intended):*

**Table I built for each past due occurrence:**

```
CREATE TABLE past_due_detail(   
    customer_id integer not null,
    first_name varchar not null,
    last_name varchar not null,
    rental_id integer not null,
    rental_date timestamp not null,
    return_date timestamp,
    title varchar not null,
    days_past_due smallint,
    primary key (rental_id),
    foreign key (customer_id) references customer(customer_id)
);
```

**Function I built for populating days past due field in table:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.days_past_due(
    rental_date timestamp without time zone,
    return_date timestamp without time zone,
    rental_duration smallint,
    last_update timestamp without time zone)
    RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
declare days_past_due int;
begin
    select ((cast(return_date as date)) - (cast(rental_date as date)) - rental_duration) where ((cast(return_date as date)) - (cast(rental_date as date)) - rental_duration) > 0 and return_date is not null
        into days_past_due;
    return days_past_due;
    select ((cast(last_update as date)) - (cast(rental_date as date)) - rental_duration) where ((cast(last_update as date)) - (cast(return_date as date)) - rental_duration) > 0 and return_date is null
        into days_past_due;
    return days_past_due;
end;
$BODY$;
```

**How I populated the past_due_detail table:**

```
insert into past_due_detail(
select rental.customer_id,first_name,last_name,rental_id,rental_date,return_date,title,days_past_due(rental_date,return_date,rental_duration,rental.last_update)
from inventory
inner join film on film.film_id = inventory.film_id
inner join rental on rental.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id
inner join customer on rental.customer_id = customer.customer_id
where days_past_due(rental_date,return_date,rental_duration,rental.last_update) > 0
order by rental_date,rental.customer_id
);
```

Comment: I only glanced briefly at this, but it has two functions (one of which has two `return` statements — is that intentional?) and one four-table join, to illustrate what sounds like a not-terribly-complex problem. And it references some external dataset. I think it would increase the chances of a good answer if you could pare it down to a [MCVE].

Comment: @TurePålsson I believe I've added more helpful information, and have provided examples to simplify the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's safe to say that your answer is not the solution. A "loop" over a single row built from two input parameters, one of which (`days_overdue`) not being used at all. Makes no sense. Burns down to just:

```sql
SELECT count(*)::smallint  -- why the cast?
FROM   past_due_detail
WHERE  days_past_due < 3
AND    customer_id = $customer;  -- $customer being your customer_id input.
```

If that's not it, clarify your ambiguous task description.

Answer (score 0):

I took a step back, and accomplished what I wanted by doing the following:

```
create or replace function pd_lt3(customer integer,days_overdue smallint)
returns table (pd_lt3 smallint)
language plpgsql
as $$
declare var_r record;
begin
    for var_r in(select customer, days_overdue)      
         loop return query select cast(count(*) as smallint) from past_due_detail where days_past_due < 3 and customer_id = customer;
    end loop;
end;
$$;
```

Comment: If you're using a loop, you're doing it **wrong**.